# What are the likely international consequences if the status quo in Jerusalem is changed?

Tags: international-relations, israel, religion

My question is based on [the news from January 3rd](https://www.timesofisrael.com/despite-report-hed-delay-ben-gvir-visits-temple-mount-for-1st-time-as-minister/), when Ben Gvir, the new National Security Minister of Israel, visited the Temple Mount in Jerusalem. It is well-known that there is a status quo in the area, and visits by far-right politicians could potentially increase tensions. This is especially true when the visiting person has oversight over the security forces that operate in the area.

This visit [resulted in an international condemnation](https://edition.cnn.com/2023/01/03/middleeast/israel-palestinians-jerusalem-ben-gvir-intl/index.html) including these statements from Jordan (the custodians of Al-Aqsa mosque) and the US (Israel's main strategic ally):

> Jordan condemned Ben Gvir’s visit in the “strongest” terms, calling it
> “a flagrant and unacceptable violation of international law, and of
> the historical and legal status quo in Jerusalem and its sanctities.”
>
> A US embassy spokesperson said: “Ambassador (Tom) Nides has been very
> clear in conversations with the Israeli government on the issue of
> preserving the status quo in Jerusalem’s holy sites. Actions that
> prevent that are unacceptable.”

The new Israeli government appears to be far to the right and Ben Gvir's visit likely indicates that his party would like to alter the status quo. From what I understand, Hamas and other religious extremists are threatening some kind of "religious war" if this occurs. Setting them aside, what is the assessment about internationally recognized actors?

I can envision the US or the EU threatening to impose sanctions. I can also imagine some neighboring Arab countries threatening to cut/downgrade diplomatic ties (which has happened with Turkey in the past), or even revoke recognition of Israel (which has happened with Iran), or even go to war. However, I have not found explicit threats from state actors, so I am struggling to comprehend what may happen.

Comment: I'm not sure why this hasn't been closed as calling for speculation since 2 of the 3 answers say nobody knows, and the third lists a lot of uncertainties. But I guess sometimes "nobody knows" is a legitimate answer?

Comment: @StuartF I suggested *possible* consequences in the question body, asking for specific likely ones. If there are no such known at the moment then "nobody knows" is a legitimate answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can't be answered. The different parties tend to speak strongly and act much less, but it's impossible to predict how much they will act.

Hamas want to be seen as protectors of Al-Aqsa, and the impression that their threats keep Israel at bay serves then well. But at present they prefer to avoid actual conflict with Israel. Their response to the latest visit was mild, but it might be different another time.

Jordanian population has a strong anti-Israeli sentiment, but the state has very useful commercial ties with Israel. So talking more and doing less serves the government well. But they won't necessarily do so in the future.

In short, it's hard to say if and how things will escalate. All parties don't want an escalation, but sometimes find themselves obligated to respond, which may lead to escalation.

Answer (score 4):

***Nobody knows***

The range of things that could happen is immense, and it's very difficult to predict what would happen. A new Arab-Israeli War could start, depending on what a few individuals in a protesting crowd do, and how Israeli security forces react to that.

The early Israeli governments seem to have been quite conscious of this, which is presumably why, once they had physical control of the Temple Mount area, they left the mosques alone and did not allow the building of new structures. However, Israeli governments of the last thirty years have inched towards a change of status for the area, seemingly confident in their military and policing power.

People who feel they have to act as if God is definitely on their side tend not to apply reasonable caution.

Answer (score 2):

Disclaimer: This question is quite hypothetical, so any answer would probably be based on common sense more than on solid proof.

Preface: It must be made clear that it's hard to say that the *official* "Status Quo" on the Temple Mount was actually compromised with Minister Ben-Gvir's visit. According to the Status Quo - i.e. the agreement between Israel and Jordan, Jews should be allowed unlimited access to the Temple Mount. See article 9:1 of the peace agreement on the website of the UN:
https://www.un.org/unispal/document/auto-insert-179122/

Ben-Gvir is also not the first Israeli minister to visit the Temple Mount while in office, Gilad Erdan (Israel's current ambbasador to the UN) visited the Temple Mount while being the National Security Minister about 5 years ago.

Answer to the question: According to my understanding (see disclaimer above):

Hamas and the other Gaza based terror groups will never miss an opportunity to shoot a few rockets - unless if Israel made it clear enough to them, that *this* time the response will be heavier than they can afford.

Jordan and Egypt will release a few angry statements - they can't afford more than that.

The UAE will also say something in order to show that they didn't become Satan's best friends.

Regarding the United States: While the US pleads for peace and stability, it's hard to see the Mother of Democracy taking action against a fellow democratic state, for allowing a religious person to visit the holiest site to his religion.

The UN might call for discussions and some powerless resolusions may come thru - a few days will pass and they will find another stupid issue to focus on, while forgetting the millions of children shivering in the cold and dark Ukraine.